# Why is the timeout always a multiple of 15 seconds?

Tags: c#, .net, sqldependency

We want to wait for a DB table to change in SQL Server 2022 and therefore use SqlDependency in our C# project. That works great but when we specify the timeout in the constructor of the class, it will always be rounded up to the next 15 seconds. I cannot find anything about that in the documentation.

We are basically doing the following:

```cs
var timeoutInSeconds = 5;
var sqlDependency = new SqlDependency(mySimpleSelectCommand, $"Service=mySampleService", timeoutInseconds);
sqlDependency.OnChange += (_, args) => SampleHandler(args);
// execute command etc.
```

The SampleHandler will be called (as expected) on timeout (= no changes were received). However, that happens after 15 seconds (whereas 5 are specified). When we specify a 20 seconds timeout, it will be called after 30 seconds. To be clear: it is NOT about connection timeouts, it is about the "SqlDependency has not received any changes" timeout.

Is that behavior expected/documented? Can it be changed? It is a bit odd as we'd like to have a different timeout.

Comment: Why do you want a short timeout in the first place? This won't make processing notification any faster, it will increase the database overhead just to provide a "nothing" message. It's *cheaper* to write a bit of client-side code that emits such a message if nothing is received.

Comment: There are several SO questions asking how to emit/do something if no action is performed for a while. Libraries like Reactive Extensions have methods like `Timeout` for exactly this scenario

Comment: Due to this being part of an integration test, we actually don't want to wait for 15s for it to pass. We are testing the application's behavior in case changes don't happen in time and the dependency times out.

Comment: It seems the real question is how to mock the system clock. In .NET 8 this is possible [using ITimer and TimeProvider](https://andrewlock.net/exploring-the-dotnet-8-preview-avoiding-flaky-tests-with-timeprovider-and-itimer/). Almost all if not all BCL classes have been updated to use TimeProvider, eg [Task.Delay(TimeSpan,TimeProvider)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay?view=net-8.0#system-threading-tasks-task-delay(system-timespan-system-timeprovider))

Comment: Unfortunately, the [Microsoft.Data.SqlClient](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient) repo doesn't return any results for `TimeProvider`. The timer resolution [is hard-coded to 15s](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/blob/769b982606bc97fee797d6c061973c28400aa362/src/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/src/Microsoft/Data/SqlClient/SqlDependencyUtils.cs#L515). You can't even use reflection to change the value.

Comment: And even [a timeout unit test](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/blob/769b982606bc97fee797d6c061973c28400aa362/src/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/tests/ManualTests/SQL/SqlNotificationTest/SqlNotificationTest.cs#L231) waits for 15 seconds instead of trying to fast-forward.

Comment: The point is that I want to try the real behavior, so messing with the system clock... meh. But the source you found (the hard-coded 15000ms) is the answer why the class behaves like that. Sadly, this is not mentioned in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@Panagiotis Kanavos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134204/panagiotis-kanavos) for digging through the .NET source code and finding the answer:

As the timer actually checks for the timeout [in 15 second intervals](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/blob/769b982606bc97fee797d6c061973c28400aa362/src/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/src/Microsoft/Data/SqlClient/SqlDependencyUtils.cs#L515), timeouts will effectively always be rounded up to the next multiple of 15 seconds.

This is odd given that I think a smarter implementation that adapts to the actual timeout that was passed would be pretty easy to implement and **at the moment there is no way of passing a timeout less than 15 seconds**.

Comment: Nothing is stopping you opening an issue on that repo to ask about this.

Comment: There are several *intentional* blockers - the timeout (not poll interval) is hard-coded so that even reflection won't be able to change it - at least not without modifying the `_timeoutTimer` object itself. Other tests in the Github repo do use reflection to modify private fields, but not this one. Second, the standard way to mock time is `TimeProvider` which was only added in .NET 8. Microsoft.Data.SqlClient has to support .NET Framework and .NET 6 though, so it can't add overloads that require .NET 8 yet.

Comment: And finally, query notifications are expensive. The server has to cache the data *and* use service broker queues to notify clients that the data changed. A short notification timeout means a short `RECEIVE` timeout and more `RECEIVE` requests. The same functionality can easily be implemented with a client-side timer that resets every time `OnChange` is fired though, without increasing the server load

Comment: Well, tbh, server load is not my concern here as this is just part of a test. In production, of course, timeouts will be much longer. We just wanted an integration test which tests the behavior in case the SqlDependency times out and didn't want to wait for at least 15 seconds, but here we go.

Ian is right that we should at least open an issue, I was planning on doing that. However, their de-facto-singleton design seems to be more "challenging" than I thought.